# tabindex not working with textboxes xul

Tags: xul

I have four textboxes like:

```
<xul:textbox value="vipin" tabindex='1'/>
<xul:textbox value="vipin1" tabindex='2'/>
<xul:textbox value="vipin2" tabindex='3'/>
<xul:textbox value="vipin3" tabindex='4'/>
```

I have implemented the tabindex on the textboxes, But tabindex not working.
how can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/textbox) is a Mozilla documentation one XUL.
[here](http://www.amplesdk.com/examples/markup/xul/input/) is a simple example on how to use it

Comment: i have used the tabindex like shown in MDN documentation but still tabindex not working for me.

Comment: there are some problems similar to your problem, for [example](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?231110-tabindex-not-working-correctly), and many more. try looking in google